# gravitational field as a spin 2 particle using gauge invariance

Tags: general-relativity, particle-physics, gauge-theory

can someone help me prove that a gravitational field corresponds to a spin 2 particle using gauge invariance.

i know about the tensor formulation of GTR and the gauge invariance in electrodynamics corresponds to a spin 1 particle because we can add a gradient of scalar field to the four vector potential.

how should i proceed for the same with the potential as g(u,v)

Comment: http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Problem_Book_in_Relativity_and_Gravitati.html?id=YtxGYnnP1PEC problem and solution 12.16

Comment: Asking about GR as a gauge theory in analogy to electrodynamics is a legitimate technical question that should not be closed. The question is even conceptual, so if it is not a duplicate it should be reopend.

Comment: No, it's not a conceptual question. This is just asking to be given a proof.